# Ignore navigation properties that have not been configured via EntityTypeConfiguration<>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a HUGE legacy data model that is represented by a `DbContext` and a big set of `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>` implementations that define the configuration for each entit in the model.

As a first step to eventually spliting the database, we are dividing the functionalities in bounded contexts. We wanted to created smaller contexts with only the mappings we need for that particular task.

For example, there may be an purchase order entity like

```
{
  Id=0,
  Address = {
     Street = "",
     City = "",
     ... etc ...
  },
  Order = {
  }
}
```

Then in the addresses bounded context, that only cares about the purchase order and its address, we created a small `DbContext` with only the type configurations for those two entities. But... it fails :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the
>   relationship represented by navigation property
>   'PurchaseOrder.Order' of type 'Order'. Either manually configure
>   the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]'
>   attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
>   'OnModelCreating'.'

I understand the complaint, it actually makese sense. But I wonder if there is a way to tell EF Core to ignore the navigation properties for which no entity type configuration has been added by default, so we can only map the parts of the existing model we want, without having to create specific entity type configurations that ignore the navigation properties we want to ignore.

Comment: It's not possible because this is the EF Core [convention for including entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types), and conventions can be overridden only with data annotations and fluent API.  And "bounded contexts* are IMHO wrong concept, at least for EF. `DbContext` == database. And database must contain all related tables. Hence `DbContext` must contain all related entities. All these not mapped tricks will only cause you problems.

Comment: I guess you are right, thanks!